# Crosstab Postgresql, problema con tipo de datos

Tags: sql, postgresql

A partir de una query, donde contabilizo los estados de las SIMS, obtengo una tabla similar a esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera cruzar la tabla por estatus por día, para lo que generé la siguiente QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
'SELECT "Change Type Name", fecha, COUNT(simstate)
  FROM "Sumadesuscriptores"
  JOIN "SIMStateRf"
  ON simstate::integer = "Change Type"
GROUP BY  "Change Type Name", fecha',
'SELECT serie FROM generate_series(1,9) AS serie') as ct(
fecha bigint, 
"Purged" bigint,
"Activated" bigint,
"Replaced" bigint,
"Deactivated" bigint,
"Inventory" bigint,
"Start" bigint,
"Retired" bigint,
"Test Ready" bigint,
"Activation Ready" bigint)
```

Pero al ejecutarla me manda el siguiente error:

```
ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: «Activation Ready»
********** Error **********
```

¿Alguien que me pueda apoyar?

Ninguna columna está nula y el resultado de los datos es un COUNT por lo que es un resultado int

Comment: ¿`generate_series` debe ser del 1 al **10** o del 1 al 9?

Comment: del 1 al 9, de lo contrario me estaría sobrando una columna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado: Primero, tenía un error en el orden de los campos; el campo fecha esta después del campo "Change Type Name", posteriormente, tenía un corrimiento en los datos cuando venían nulos, para lo que realicé un ordenamiento de los valores, así es como quedó la QUERY final:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
'SELECT  date(fecha::text),"Change Type Name", COUNT(simstate)
  FROM "Sumadesuscriptores"
  JOIN "SIMStateRf"
  ON simstate::integer = "Change Type"
GROUP BY  "Change Type Name", fecha ORDER BY fecha',
 $$VALUES ('Activated'::text),
 ('Activation Ready'::text),
 ('Deactivated'::text),
 ('Inventory'::text),
 ('Purged'::text),
 ('Replaced'::text),
 ('Retired'::text),
 ('Start'::text),
 ('Test Ready'::text)
 $$
 ) as ct(
fecha date, 
"Activated" bigint,
"Activation Ready" bigint,
"Deactivated" bigint,
"Inventory" bigint,
"Purged" bigint,
"Replaced" bigint,
"Retired" bigint,
"Start" bigint,
"Test Ready" bigint)
```

[Me basé en este ejemplo para ordenar los valores nulos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que invertir las columnas "Change Type Name" y fecha en el SELECT.

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
'SELECT fecha, "Change Type Name", COUNT(simstate)
  FROM "Sumadesuscriptores"
  JOIN "SIMStateRf" ON simstate::integer = "Change Type"
GROUP BY  "Change Type Name", fecha',
'SELECT serie FROM generate_series(1,9) AS serie') as ct(
fecha bigint, 
"Purged" bigint,
"Activated" bigint,
"Replaced" bigint,
"Deactivated" bigint,
"Inventory" bigint,
"Start" bigint,
"Retired" bigint,
"Test Ready" bigint,
"Activation Ready" bigint)
```

La columna que identifica cada fila (row_name), y las columnas extra deben ir primero (tanto en el SELECT como al definir las columnas de salida). Las últimas columnas del SELECT son la categoría y el valor.

Se deben definir la cantidad apropiada de columnas de salida y del tipo correcto (que dependen de la cantidad de categorías que hayan), especificando primero la columna que identifica cada fila, luego las columnas extras, y finalmente una columna por cada categoría que haya.